# Javascript slide form Jquery, Prototype, or pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, slide

I am a newby and would like some professiona advice about the following:

I want to create a form.

The user fills in one part and clicks 'next'.
The form slides to the left and a new part of the form slides in from the right.

Does anyone have any advice as to the way to go. 
Jquery, Prototype, or just plain old javascript.

I am using Ruby on Rails3, Mac OSX10.6, Ruby 1.9.2

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why is your question tagged "Java"?

Comment: I removed the java tag since I can't see a relation to Java.

Comment: my bad, I meant to include the tag javascript.

Comment: I have removed the `prototype` tag (which should be `prototypejs`), because none of the posts contain any relevant information for Prototype.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already jQuery plugins to do this kind of thing. Take a look at http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/ for example.

Comment: Personally i was thinking throw a jcarousel on a `<form>` and use the `<fieldset>`'s as slides... :-) I usually try and stay away from all but the most versatile plugins - this usually mean jQueryUI, jCarousel, Cycle and sometimes jScrollpane if im super lazy. Barring those i usually jsut use the UI elements with custom code to do whatever... tends to cut down on plugin bloat.

Comment: Technically this isn't actually a jQuery plugin, but that link is very relevant.

Comment: Thanks that is exaclty what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with jQuery and jQuery UI, because it's the most successful and has the biggest community. See the "[which-javascript-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs)" question on SO. The slide effect can be found [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide).

Plain JavaScript is no option. Implementing these effects is a ton of work, especially doing it cross browser.